# Build a inductance or capacitance meter

Tags: voltage, transistors, power, current, resistors

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hi all, I am trying to understand the working principle of a Inductor or Capacitance meter and these circuit are common. Looking at the diagrams, **the quality factor (sensitivity to frequency change) will increase which is good** as **resistance is decrease**. But, the problem is the resistor will get heat up to a hot level as the resistance decreases. Are there any better alternatives out there that is much more efficient and sensitive to build an inductance or a capacitance meter?

From my view, if I were to use a high value resistor which means less quality factor (less sensitive to frequency change), I could just use an op-amp to amplify it so that the circuit is more sensitive to frequency change and **is this how it is done in most of the LCR meter**?

Comment: That's not really how you build a meter. It's just more of how those circuits behave. To measure capacitance all you have to do is charge up the cap through a resistor and measure how long it takes to reach the charge voltage (or within some tolerance of it). You can do something similar with an inductor except with current. Measuring L, C, and R when you know what it is also different than measuring general imepdance or reactance when you don't know if it is L, C, R, or a combination thereof. In that case inject a sine wave and measure the current and phase.

Comment: A simple method is to build a LC oscillator. To measure L you use a capacitor of known value and for C you use a L of known value. From the resultant frequency and reference L/C you can derive the value of the component under test. There's a classic circuit using a LM311 comparator that should be found on the web.

Comment: Since this is about a meter, what is the intended method of READING the meter?    Moving needle, or computer-gets-a-message, or numeric display, or converts-to-voltage and voltmeter, or adjust-dial-for-null reading on detector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily measure capacitance using a Schering bridge and inductance using a Maxwell bridge your way of measuring capacitance or inductance isn't really the way we do it.